# Is there any method to insert link in between string

Tags: javascript, string, variables, url

I need to insert a link inside a string.
Something like this...

```
var txtarea="This is my link "+www.abcd.com\contacts+ ";
```

The String+link stored in variable 'txtarea' is send to webpage using POST method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [link()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) approach:

```js
var url = "http://www.abcd.com/contacts";
var txtarea = "This is my link: " + url.link(url);
document.write(txtarea);
```